# MySQL Command Line Client option not appearing under MySQL in Programs

Tags: mysql, shortcuts

I use Windows 7 OS and downloaded both SQL Server 5.1 AND ODBC driver to go with it, and successfully installed both and configured an SQL Instance.

However, I now (or before installing ODBC) have no option of MYSQL Coimmand Line Client under my MySQL item under Start>Programs.

So I have to open an sql command line from DOS which means closing and opening several directories to get there.

How do I get my shortcut?
Thanks, Mukesh.

Answer (score 0):

Simply make a copy of the standard "Command Prompt" shortcut, and name it "MySQL Command Prompt". Then right-click, choose *Properties*, and set the "Working directory" to wherever MySQL commands are installed.

---

Also, "Command Prompt" **is not DOS**.